# Google Chart ticks not displaying at all

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have a problem with the vaxis.ticks option in google charts.

My code does work and the chart is correct, but the strings in the ticks array are ignored and the initial numbers are displaying. No errors or warnings.

I cant seem to find a solution for this problem.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/chart/eta/lane/45',
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function (response) {
    var array = [];
    var ticks = [];
    array.push(['Time', 'line 1', 'line 2', 'line 3', 'line 4']);
    $.each(response, function (key, row) {
        array.push([new Date(row[0]), row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4]]);
        if(row[1])
            ticks.push({v: row[1], f: secondsToTime(row[1])});
        if(row[2])
            ticks.push({v: row[2], f: secondsToTime(row[2])});
        if(row[3])
            ticks.push({v: row[3], f: secondsToTime(row[3])});
        if(row[4])
            ticks.push({v: row[4], f: secondsToTime(row[4])});
    });
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['line']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {

        var datatable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(array);

        var options = {
            width: 1000,
            height: 800,
            legend: {position: 'none'},
            hAxis: {
                format: 'd.M.yyyy H:mm'
            },
            vAxis: {
                title: "Δ ETA",
                ticks: ticks
            }
        };

        var container = document.getElementById('chart');
        var chart = new google.charts.Line(container);

        chart.draw(datatable, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
    }
});

function secondsToTime(seconds) {
    var isNegative = false;
    if(seconds < 0) {
        seconds = Math.abs(seconds);
        isNegative = true;
    }
    return (isNegative ? '-' : '') + Math.floor(seconds / 3600) + ':' + Math.floor((seconds%3600) / 60);
}
```

Example AJAX response:

```
[
    ["2018-07-25 17:09:24",311,4490,null,-10994],
    ["2018-07-25 17:16:20",364,4543,null,-11047],
    ["2018-07-25 17:19:29",412,4591,null,-11095],
    ["2018-07-25 17:21:25",528,4707,null,-11211],
    ["2018-07-25 17:21:43",546,4725,null,-11229],
    ["2018-07-25 17:22:01",564,4743,null,-11247],
    ["2018-07-25 17:22:18",581,4760,null,-11264],
    ["2018-07-25 17:22:38",601,4780,null,-11284],
    ["2018-07-25 17:22:57",620,4799,null,-11303],
    ["2018-07-25 17:23:17",640,4819,null,-11323],
    ["2018-07-25 17:23:36",659,null,5573,-11342],
    ["2018-07-25 17:23:56",616,null,5530,-11299],
    ["2018-07-25 17:28:02",862,null,5776,-11545]
]
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2n2Rg.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're using a *Material* chart vs. a *Classic* chart

there are several options that are not supported by *Material* charts,
see --> [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)

this includes --> `{hAxis,vAxis,hAxes.*,vAxes.*}.ticks`

---

*Material* = `packages: ['line']` -- `google.charts.Line`

*Classic* = `packages: ['corechart']` -- `google.visualization.LineChart`

if you switch to *Classic*, there is an option to make the chart **similar** to *Material*

```
theme: 'material'
```

---

using *Classic* the `ticks` will appear, however, there also needs to be enough room to display the `ticks`

with the example data, the scale of the y-axis is so large, there won't be enough room to display them all

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
    packages: ['corechart']
}).then(getData);

function getData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/chart/eta/lane/45',
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(drawChart).fail(function () {
        drawChart([
            ["2018-07-25 17:09:24",311,4490,null,-10994],
            ["2018-07-25 17:16:20",364,4543,null,-11047],
            ["2018-07-25 17:19:29",412,4591,null,-11095],
            ["2018-07-25 17:21:25",528,4707,null,-11211],
            ["2018-07-25 17:21:43",546,4725,null,-11229],
            ["2018-07-25 17:22:01",564,4743,null,-11247],
            ["2018-07-25 17:22:18",581,4760,null,-11264],
            ["2018-07-25 17:22:38",601,4780,null,-11284],
            ["2018-07-25 17:22:57",620,4799,null,-11303],
            ["2018-07-25 17:23:17",640,4819,null,-11323],
            ["2018-07-25 17:23:36",659,null,5573,-11342],
            ["2018-07-25 17:23:56",616,null,5530,-11299],
            ["2018-07-25 17:28:02",862,null,5776,-11545]
        ]);
    });
}

function drawChart(response) {
    var array = [];
    var ticks = [];
    array.push(['Time', 'line 1', 'line 2', 'line 3', 'line 4']);
    $.each(response, function (key, row) {
        array.push([new Date(row[0]), row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4]]);
        if(row[1])
            ticks.push({v: row[1], f: secondsToTime(row[1])});
        if(row[2])
            ticks.push({v: row[2], f: secondsToTime(row[2])});
        if(row[3])
            ticks.push({v: row[3], f: secondsToTime(row[3])});
        if(row[4])
            ticks.push({v: row[4], f: secondsToTime(row[4])});
    });

    var datatable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(array);

    var options = {
        theme: 'material',
        width: 1000,
        height: 800,
        legend: {position: 'none'},
        hAxis: {
            format: 'd.M.yyyy H:mm'
        },
        vAxis: {
            title: "? ETA",
            ticks: ticks
        }
    };

    var container = document.getElementById('chart');
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(container);

    chart.draw(datatable, options);
}

function secondsToTime(seconds) {
    var isNegative = false;
    if(seconds < 0) {
        seconds = Math.abs(seconds);
        isNegative = true;
    }
    return (isNegative ? '-' : '') + Math.floor(seconds / 3600) + ':' + Math.floor((seconds%3600) / 60);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

---

**note**: recommend loading google charts first, before getting the data
google charts only needs to be loaded once per page load, not per chart to be drawn
by default, `google.charts.load` will wait for the page to load, so it can be used in place of `$(document).ready` or other similar functions
a setup similar to above will allow you to draw multiple charts or make multiple ajax calls,
while only loading google charts once...

Comment: Thank you so much. Works like a charm!